# Como gerar um numero sequencial automatico no C#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde..

Tenho um txtbox1.Tex no meu formulário, e preciso gerar um numero sequencial de 2 dígitos automaticamente. EX 01, 02, 03 e assim sucessivamente, e mostra no txtbox.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia postar oque já foi desenvolvido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No formulário:

```
private int _contador = 0;
```

No método no qual você vai alterar o texto:

```
this._contador++;
this.txtBox1.Text = this._contador.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

O método [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe `String` recebe dois parâmetros. O primeiro diz o comprimento mínimo que você deseja ter, e o segundo diz com qual caractere você vai fazer preenchimento à esquerda.

Comment: Renan muito obrigado, resolvido parte do meu problema agora preciso dar sequencia no código. vlw

Answer (score -1):

Cria um metodo do Genero

```
private void Gerar()
{
  // Gerando Código Incremento
   this._contador++;
   this.Codigo.Text = this._contador.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
 }
```

no Lod

```
 private void Cliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

            Gerar();

  }
```